# Migrate custom domain outlook.com account to Office 365 Business

Tags: email, domain, office365, outlook.com

I have a custom domain outlook.com account which was created years ago and now it can't be managed through domains.live.com, lets say it is:

user@domain.com

I would like to subscribe Office 365 for Business and add my domain into it to manage all my accounts and emails, including that user@domain.com.

What happen with all of my emails, contacts, calendar, and other data, which are currently linked with user@domain.com (old custom domain outlook.com account) after adding it to Office 365 subscription?

Would it be erased so I will never see my current data?

Comment: You can also use the Connected Accounts feature to view your old emails from within Office 365 - assuming you have POP3/IMAP4 access to the mail server - see https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Connect-email-accounts-in-Outlook-on-the-web-d7012ff0-924f-4f78-8aca-c3912d886c4d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emails and content will remain in Outlook.com. Your logons to Outlook.com will continue to work, but new accounts can not be added.

You set up the domain in O365, update your DNS records and use the new service as before.  Your users will need to migrate data if they want it all in one place, and that is done from email client while connected to both services.

Microsoft has a support page available for this scenario: 
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/migrate-custom-domain