# Migrate working Windows Live Domain to new Office 365 Business custom domain

Tags: email, dns, office365, domain

So, basically the situation is as follows. Around 2013-2014 I created a domain using my family name (minkov.mx) and used Windows Live Domains to create a custom e-mail with it. Everything was working fine until Microsoft decided to discontinue/charge for the service and there was no longer access to the Admin Panel of the service. If you had created e-mails before you still could use them, but there was no way to create/modify/delete existing accounts.

So, with recent changes in policy, now my account is 95% full and since I use it for a bunch of stuff I want to move it to a Office 365 Business, since the Family plan doesn't allow for a custom domain.

My main concern is, if I add the domain and all the process to my Office Admin account, is there any probability I might lose access to the information? I have seen that sometimes when you sign in one of those accounts it actually asks you to select which account you want to log in, would this be similar?

Basically what I want to do is create my Business 365 Account and transfer all my info there using Outlook or something similar.

I saw [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/969207/692217), but the link is no longer available.

Answer (score 0):

Well, turns out it was easier than I thought. What happens is that when you create the new domain on Microsoft 365 and point your DNS records there, your old e-mail just stops receiving, and since it's on a different server system it just stays there.

Then, the tricky part was since I was using Outlook to copy and sync my e-mails from the old account to the new account, and Outlook doesn't let me add 2 equally named accounts, what I did was I created a backup@minkov.mx account, added it to my Outlook, copied all the e-mails from the old account and once it was synced I just went to the Microsoft 365 Admin and renamed the account.

The syncing was slow though, but in the end it's working fine.